# iphone app: drag drop UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to do a drag drop in an iphone app. I have a main view that contains multiple layers of views.

I placed:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

in the main view but this does not get called. I am able to load a thumbnail image on the view when the user touches for the first time. I try to drag the `UIImageView` around but the `touchesMoved:` is not being called.

here is some code: (this is the drag image that is loaded when the user touches the view, it load and is placed underneth the cursor)

```
[dragImage addTarget:self action:@selector(endDrag) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
[dragImage addTarget:self action:@selector(endDrag) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[dragImage addTarget:self action:@selector(endDrag) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

Comment: Where did you implement `touchesMove:`? Remember it's a method of `UIViewController`, not `UIView`...

Comment: do yourself a favor and use GestureRecognizer

Comment: I have it in the ViewController level. The event is firing only after I move off the screen then come back on the screen while my mouse is down.  I suspect it has something to do with placing the drag image under the moouse with dragImage.Center = point. Something is eating the event and is not bubbling it up or something..  If touchesMove doesnt fire it might be ok if dragImage fires the DragInside event. but that is not firing either

Comment: the DragInsde selector only detects and fires after I lift the mouse and then touch it again. (I load a dragImage dynamically into the View Controller when a touch event happens. I place this drag image centered where the touch is; which is underneath the mouse in the simulator)

Comment: @Saphrosit — the `touches…` methods are declared twice: in UIResponder and Gesturerecognizer. As UIViewController inherits form UIResponder, it is possible, to use them there too. [See the responder chain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW5)

Comment: What would happen if I touch the screen and hold ; then I load a UIImageView and place it where the current touch is. Will the new UIImageView that is placed under the cursor dectect touches?  It seems like it will detect it only after I untouch then retouch.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do to drag an image around the screen:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[imageView_ addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

And then:

```
-(void)move:(id)sender {

    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
        firstY = [[sender view] center].y;
    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);
    [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

}
```

Comment: [see the touches sample code for this approach](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435)

Comment: I get the same result with your code. I can only drag the image only after I touch it again. I dont know how to best explain it.

Comment: touchesMoved is fired once then I have to untouch then retouch to make it behave as expected. Why is that?

Comment: I discovered that this is an issue only in IOS 5.0 Simulator. I got it to work in ios 4.3 simulator.

Comment: how can i detect when the user removes his finger and then do something .. ?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is place the UIImageView inside a UIControl (which will respond to UIControlEventTouchDragInside).

```
UIControl *dragImageControl = [[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:dragImageView.frame];
        [dragImageControl addSubview:dragImageView];

[self.view addSubview:dragImageControl];

[dragImageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTouch:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[dragImageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

and in imageMoved, you can have this code:

```
- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UIControl *control = sender;
    control.center = point;
}
```